# How to import YRBS ASCII .dat file into R

Tags: r, ascii

I'm trying to import the YRBS ASCII .dat file [found here](https://www.cdc.gov/healthyyouth/data/yrbs/data.htm) to analyze in R, but I'm having trouble importing the file. I followed the recommendations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149932/import-ascii-file-into-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664075/import-dat-file-into-r) but none seem to work. More specifically, it's still showing up as being one column/variable in R with 14,765 observations.

I've tried using the `readLines()`, `read.table`, and `read.csv` functions but none seem to be separating the columns.

Here are the specific codes I tried:

```
readLines("D:/Projects/XXH2017_YRBS_Data.dat", n=5)
read.csv("D:/Projects/XXH2017_YRBS_Data.dat", header = FALSE)
read.table("D:/Projects/XXH2017_YRBS_Data.dat", header = FALSE)
```

readLines and read.csv only provided one column and I got an error message from using read.table that stated that line 1 did not have 23 elements (which I'm assuming is just referring to the missing values?).
The data also starts from line 1 so I cannot use `skip = 1` like some have suggested online.

How do I import this file into R so that I can separate the columns?