# Unable to load ASCII file into R

Tags: r, ascii

I've followed a couple of these posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149932/import-ascii-file-into-r) and [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-to-input-data-into-r/) but am still struggling with loading an ASCII file.

I'm trying to pull down the county-level [Area Health Resources File](https://data.hrsa.gov//DataDownload/AHRF/AHRF_2017-2018.ZIP) but it's not loading correctly. I've now tried:

```
> df <- read.table("DATA/ahrf2018.asc")
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 312 elements
> dim(df)
[1] 3350    5
> df <- read.delim("DATA/ahrf2018.asc")
> dim(df)
[1] 3229    1
> df <- read.csv("DATA/ahrf2018.asc")
> dim(df)
[1] 3350    5
> df <- read.csv("DATA/ahrf2018.asc", header = FALSE, skip = 1)
> dim(df)
[1] 3350    6
```

And I looked into the `LaF` package, but don't know the column types which are required.

Is there something painfully simple I am overlooking?

EDIT:
Example of output, where columns not getting created:

```
    V1
1  01001AHRF 01001               20181821232435Alabama            ALAutauga                  Autauga
2  01003AHRF 01003               20181821232435Alabama            ALBaldwin                  Baldwin
3  01005AHRF 01005               20181821232435Alabama            ALBarbour                  Barbour
4     01007AHRF 01007               20181821232435Alabama            ALBibb                     Bibb
```

Comment: You should provide the first several lines of your data, or give a direct link to it.  The link at the top of your message points to a site with tons of data, and we are not going to search for a file called ahrf2018.asc at the site.

Comment: This is not a complete question, because we can't see what your ASCII looks like.  Please include a sample from that file, including the header and a few rows.  Most likely, you just need to slightly alter your call to `read.table` or `read.csv`.

Comment: @joran the documentation is related to the methodology for data elements and not for using the files.